# When an android service is really started?

Tags: android, service

I have tested this method:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I call a bindService() in my activity without startService(), my service is running (checked it with the prevoious method) but I was thinking that only startService() can start a service!

So I just want to know when a service has really begun: with startService() or binService()

Just a comment, Only when I call unBindService(), the previous method return false.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`getRunningServices()` returns the running services. Services will be running if they have been started by `startService()` or bound to via `bindService()`.

Comment: so when I just call binService(), why isMyServiceRunning() method return true??? that is my question.

Comment: @SamySeniorAndroidDeveloper: Because your service is running. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: ok thanks but a service start really when onStartCommand() method (from Service class) is called but when I have used only bindService(), onStartCommand() method is not called.

Comment: @SamySeniorAndroidDeveloper: Correct. In the English language, "run" is a different word than "start". `getRunningServices()` returns the **running** services, which includes both started services and bound services.

Comment: @CCommonsWare  Yes before run, you need start ;) Thanks for clarifications!

Comment: @SamySeniorAndroidDeveloper: "before run, you need start", no. **Running** services includes **both** started services **and** bound services. There are many Android developer sites on the Internet, supporting a wide range of languages. I have a number of them listed at http://www.andglobe.com. You may wish to find a site that is in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: @CCommonsWare I'm not totally convinced because if I take the example of the Thread.
Thread.run () is called grace Thread.start ()
The thread starts and then turns